# __FUNCTION__ and friends act weird in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, function, clang, c-preprocessor

This works

```
printf("%s body\n",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
```

But this does not (Error `Expected ')'`):

```
printf(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__" body\n");
```

I can't get the IDE to show me what `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` evaluates to to determine why it does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is not a macro](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html). It behaves like a static variable created on the fly scoped in that function.

The last paragraph in the link above reads:

> These identifiers are not preprocessor macros. In GCC 3.3 and earlier, in C only, `__FUNCTION__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` were treated as string literals; they could be used to initialize char arrays, and they could be concatenated with other string literals. GCC 3.4 and later treat them as variables, like `__func__`. In C++, `__FUNCTION__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` have always been variables.

Comment: @sixletter Not sure that this is the best reference since the question is about clang … but it’s the first one I’ve found as well.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: confusingly it looks like clang defines it as a macro for Microsoft, but not for other platforms.

Comment: @sixletter Apparently it aims for highest compatibility (according to the comments) – which makes sense, but it’s weird since MSVC doesn’t even known `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` (and the clang developers even mention that in a comment).